# Nginx Reverse Proxy on docker containers : 404 redirections

Tags: docker, nginx, jenkins, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm trying to deploy a docker-compose stack that contains a Nginx service to manage the others like Jenkins or Grafana. However, when I target my Jenkins service like http://myapp.fr/jenkins, the homepage of the service will redirect to the login page at this URL: http://myapp.fr/login?from=%2F. How I can fix this for all services to prefix with the service name for all pages of it (like http://myapp.fr/jenkins/login?from=%2F).

My stack looks like this :

```html
version: "3.7"
services:
  ## NGINX ##
  web:
    image: nginx
    container_name: myapp_nginx
    volumes:
    - ./config/nginx/templates:/etc/nginx/templates
    - ./config/nginx/include.d:/etc/nginx/include.d
    - ./config/nginx/www:/var/www/certbot
    ports:
    - "80:80"
    - "443:443"
    environment:
    - NGINX_HOST=myapp.fr
    - NGINX_PORT=80
    networks:
    - myapp
  ## JENKINS ##
  jenkins:
    build:
      context: ./dockerfile/jenkins
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: myapp_jenkins
    hostname: jenkins.myapp.fr
    privileged: true
    user: root
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 50000:50000
    volumes:
      - ~/jenkins:/var/jenkins_home
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /usr/local/bin/docker:/usr/local/bin/docker
    restart: always
    networks:
    - myapp
  ## GRAFANA ##
  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana-enterprise:8.2.0
    container_name: myapp_grafana
    hostname: grafana.myapp.fr
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    user: "104"
    networks:
    - myapp

networks:
  myapp:
    driver: bridge
```

My default.conf of nginx is in one of my docker volumes and it looks like this :

```html
server {
    listen       80;
    listen  [::]:80;
    server_name  myapp.fr;

    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    location /jenkins/ {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin '*';
        proxy_pass   http://jenkins.myapp.fr:8080/;
    }

    location /grafana/ {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin '*';
        proxy_pass   http://grafana.myapp.fr:3000/;
    }

    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin '*';
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers 'User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Authorization,Access-Control-Allow-Origin';
    
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

When I began the deploy, I use a docker-compose up -d command and all services are running. myapp.fr show the nginx index. However, if I specified the subpath myapp.fr/jenkins, it will be showig a 404 error because of a redirection to http://myapp.fr/login?from=%2F

How I can fix this for all services to prefix service name for all pages of it (like http://myapp.fr/jenkins/login?from=%2F).

Thanks

Comment: You have to look at the configuration of each service to let them know you’ve added a prefix to the URL. They won’t magically know where you’ve put them

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell Jenkins that you are using an additional context path, so it generates all the redirections with the added context. You can do this by passing the `--prefix=/jenkins` on startup. You can pass this through `JENKINS_OPTS` environment variable as well. Following is how you can pass this to `docker run`.

```
docker run --name myjenkins -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 --env JENKINS_OPTS="--prefix=/jenkins" jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

**Update**

Following is a sample NginX configuration you can use. Note the `proxy_redirect` option specified, which makes sure all redirect URLs are changed to your correct Hostname.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name jenkins.ycr.com;

    location /jenkins {
            proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:8081;
            proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:8081/ http://jenkins.ycr.com/;
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I usually test this configuration but this is the same error with a 404 code error. The myapp.fr/jenkins is not found.

Do you think I must edit some nginx config after ?

Comment: @Gati Yes, you have to change the NginX configs accordingly. Please check the updated answer.